# Insert function in C Binary Tree?

Tags: c, tree

My Binary Tree code in C isn't running at all and I'm not sure exactly why. Is there anything blatantly wrong in the function? It runs with just one insert use, but any more and it stops working. It's just supposed to be a simple function that inserts ints at their right place along the tree.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct trees Tree;
struct trees {
    int data;
    Tree *left;
    Tree *right;
};

Tree *inicio=NULL; 


void insert(int n){
        Tree *novo = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
        Tree *aux;
        Tree *pai;

        novo->data=n;
        novo->left=NULL;
        novo->right=NULL;
    if(inicio==NULL){
            inicio = novo;
            return;
    } else {
        aux = inicio;
        pai = NULL;
        while(1){
            pai = aux;
            if(n>pai->data){
                aux=aux->right;
                if(aux==NULL){
                    pai->right=novo;
                    return;
            } else {
                aux=aux->left;
                if(aux==NULL){
                    pai->left=novo;
                    return;
                }

            }
            }
        }
    }   
}

int main() {
    insert(9);
    insert(8);

    printf("[%p] -> (%p, %d, %p)\n",inicio,inicio->left,inicio->data,inicio->right);    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fix up your formatting and you may find the problem. In particular, use consistent indentation. Your `if/else` blocks are not grouped the way you intended.

Comment: I see the problem now, thanks!

Comment: There's little merit to keeping this post open — the problem is very specific rather than usefully generic.  Please delete it.

Comment: I'll observe that it is more normal to pass and return pointers to the root of the tree to an insert function — if only so you are not constrained to a single list as you are with `inicio` as the global variable that holds the pointer to the start of the list.

Answer (score 1):

to illustrate @kaylum point, here is the relevant part reformatted

```
while(1){
    pai = aux;
    if(n>pai->data){
        aux=aux->right;
        if(aux==NULL){
            pai->right=novo;
            return;
        } // end if(aux==NULL)
        else
        {  // else => aux != NULL
           aux=aux->left;
           if(aux==NULL){
               pai->left=novo;
               return;
           } // end if(aux==NULL)
        } // end else
    } // end if(n>pai->data)
} // end while
```

Please Note that `else` after `return` are pointless noise

```
while(1){
    pai = aux;
    if(n > pai->data){
        aux = aux->right;
        if(aux == NULL){
            pai->right = novo;
            return;
        }
        continue; // skip to next loop
    }
    // implying (n <= pai->data)
    aux = aux->left;
    if(aux == NULL){
        pai->left = novo;
        return;
    }
}
```

"Better" implementation would probably use pointer to pointer and reduce redundant code.

```
void insert(int n)
{
    Tree **pp = &inicio;

    while (*pp)
    {
        if ((*pp)->data < n)
            pp = &(*pp)->right;
        else
            pp = &(*pp)->left;
    }

    *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
    if (*pp)
    {
        (*pp)->data = n;
        (*pp)->left = (*pp)->right = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for adding the "better" implementation @WhozCraig, but I wanted to leave the exercise to DaviAtella

Comment: I understand. It is my experience if someone struggles with pointers, they're going to have nightmares with pointers to pointers. You're correct it's a much better implementation, and having *both* in the same answer allows future readers to see how both methods achieve the same result.

Comment: Good point, but I would hate gaining reputation from your addition